# PHP MySQL Unknown column in 'on clause'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Keep getting this error whenever I try to run my mysql query: `Unknown column 'tt.uid' in 'on clause'`
Which is weird since the column exists in my table.

Here's my PHP:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM test_text tt, users u JOIN test_text ON tt.uid = u.id WHERE u.username IN ('$friends')") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

`$friends` looks like this: `'jcarter','pcoulson'` And is created dynamically
I want to select everything from both tables where the username is equal to a username in my friends string.

I don't really understand how the above query is supposed to work, I got it from a php forum. The way I understand it is that the query selects everything in the users table where the username is a username in my friends string. Then it selects everything from test_text table where the user id from the users table is equal to the user id in the test_text table. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I added a foreign key to `test_text.uid` that links the the `user.id column`.

`uid` is a column that exists in my `test_text` table. So I don't know why I'm getting that error. Maybe it's my syntax?

My tables look like this:

users table:

```
------------------------------------------
| id | username | first_name | last_name |
-----+----------+------------+------------
|  1 | jcarter  | Jake       | Carter    |
|  2 | pcoulson | Phil       | Coulson   |
------------------------------------------
```

test_text table:

```
----------------------------
| pid  | post_body   | uid |
-------+-------------+------
|   1  | hello world |   1 |
|   2  | foo bar     |   2 |
|   3  | whats up    |   1 |
----------------------------
```

Comment: What are you trying to link to what? CDo you mean `SELECT * FROM test_text tt JOIN  users u ON tt.uid = u.id AND u.username ...`

Comment: You're selecting from both tables. I'd do something like: SELECT * FROM users u inner join test_text tt on tt.uid=u.id WHERE ... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean to use

```
SELECT * FROM test_text tt JOIN users u ON tt.uid = u.id WHERE u.username IN ('$friends')
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be you are joining 3 tables where you probably mean to join 2:

```
SELECT * FROM test_text tt, users u JOIN test_text
```

Should probably be:

```
SELECT * FROM users u JOIN test_text tt
```